# fetch user media from instagram api without user id

Tags: api, instagram

I'm working on an instagram web client and i'm trying to get users media to come up if I type the user's username in the address bar. Also I don't want the user's id to show in the address bar. here's the site - http://writethefuturegroup.com/photo-client/. To get the user's media, I passed the ID in the address. But if you go to other web clients the ID doesn't show in the address bar and you can get a user's media by just entering their username in the address bar. I would like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make 2 API calls to get user media by username, first use search API to search for the username, if the username exists then it will be in the API response, use a IF statement to check that the username matches and then get the corresponding user ID, use this ID to make another API call to get user media.

1. First use the user search API endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=1&q=USERNAME` to search the username,
2. In the API response if the user.username == USERNAME you searched for, then get user.id
3. Make another call to get user media using the user id, use the API endpoint: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/media/recent/`

Comment: I love this idea. Now i'm having trouble passing the gotten id. I tried $content['data']['id'] and $content['id'] but it's null.

Comment: alright. Just figured it out. My bad. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: Not able to retrieve data for anyother user name.